# How to get database name from config.php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm using 3 databases for my project. I'm trying to get the name of different databases defined in the config file.

Is it possible to get the name of the database in the controller??

Here is the config file code. I want to get the names of three databases such as 'default' 'database2' 'database3'... 
How can i get it in the controller ???

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'acp_demo';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;


$db['database2']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['database2']['username'] = 'root';
$db['database2']['password'] = '';
$db['database2']['database'] = 'acp_demo1';
$db['database2']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['database2']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['database2']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['database2']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['database2']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['database2']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['database2']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['database2']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['database2']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['database2']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['database2']['stricton'] = FALSE;


$db['database3']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['database3']['username'] = 'root';
$db['database3']['password'] = '';
$db['database3']['database'] = 'acp';
$db['database3']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['database3']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['database3']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['database3']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['database3']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['database3']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['database3']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['database3']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['database3']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['database3']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['database3']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: First of all, which framework are you using?

Comment: Codeigniter Framework..

Answer (score 0):

After a little bit of digging around through the code, I have come up with this function (I tested it in a helper file), that will return the list of database groups, as an array. It may not be the best way to achieve this, but it works.

```
function get_db_groups()
{
    $return = array();

    // Found this in ./system/database/DB.php
    // Is the config file in the environment folder?
    if ( ! file_exists($file_path = APPPATH.'config/'.ENVIRONMENT.'/database.php')
        && ! file_exists($file_path = APPPATH.'config/database.php'))
    {
        show_error('The configuration file database.php does not exist.');
    }

    include($file_path);

    // Now we can access the $db
    foreach ($db as $key => $val)
    {
        $return[] = $key;
    }

    return $return;

}
```

Then, I can get the names like this;

```
print_r(get_db_groups());
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the config Item
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/config.html

$this->config->item('db');